# What is wrong in this Perl expression?

Tags: perl, variables, if-statement

What's the problem with following. I am getting `$attribute not defined` error.

```
if (my $attribute = $Data->{'is_new'} and $attribute eq 'Y') {
}
```

Comment: What version of perl gives you an "$attribute not defined" message? I cannot find that message anywhere in perldiag.pod...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're being too clever. Just do this:

```
my $attribute = $Data->{'is_new'};

if (defined $attribute && $attribute eq 'Y') { ... }
```

The problems are twofold:

- You have an extra `)` in your if
- `my` in expression context binds very tightly; `$attribute` is not in lexical scope until the *body of the conditional statement* that contains it, so the other branch of the `and` cannot access it. You need to lift it to the containing context, as in my example.

Comment: Under `use strict;`, I believe that if the `defined` fails, the assignment generates a warning first, doesn't it (because `$Data->{'is_new'}` must be undefined)?  Of course, it is not clear whether the questioner is so expert that `use strict;` is optional -- I've only been coding in Perl for close to 20 years and I know I can't afford not to use `use strict;` (or `use warnings;`).

Comment: use strict has no runtime effect; it is a lexical _error_ (not warning) and will fail the compilation because `$attribute` is not in scope. Assuming `$Data` is in scope it will not complain about `$Data` (`use warnings;` however might if it does turn out undefined)

Comment: That's not true. `if (my $x = foo()) { ... $x ... }` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @ikegami, yes, but in this case, it does not extend to the rest of the expression (tested with perl 5.10, and as we all know the perl interpreter _is_ the specification).

Comment: @bdonlan, That may be, but that's not what you said. You said it's scoped to the `my` itself, when 1) it's scope extends far beyond that, and 2) it doesn't even come into scope until later than that. (See my answer for more details on (2)).

Answer (score 10):

`use strict;` would have found the problem.

```
$ perl -e'use strict; my $attribute = "..." and $attribute eq "Y";'
Global symbol "$attribute" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

A `my` declaration only has an effect on subsequent statements, not the the statement in which the declaration is is located. (Same goes for the `our` and `local` declarations.) That means the `$attribute` that you create with `my` and to which you assign is a different variable than the `$attribute` you compare to `Y`. You want

```
my $attribute = $Data->{'is_new'};
if ($attribute eq 'Y') { ... }
```

Now, if `$Data->{is_new}` doesn't exist or is undefined, `$attribute` will be undefined, and comparing it to `Y` will issue a warning. You can avoid this warning as follows:

```
my $attribute = $Data->{'is_new'};
if (defined($attribute) && $attribute eq 'Y') { ... }
```

Alternatively: (5.10+)

```
my $attribute = $Data->{'is_new'};
if (($attribute // '') eq 'Y') { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good. I just want to add that if you want to avoid cluttering the surrounding scope with the `$attribute` variable you could do:

```
if (($Data->{'is_new'} || '') eq 'Y') {
    # do stuff
}
```

This also works with `strict` and `warnings`.

Answer (score 0):

Like has already been mentioned, you cannot declare a variable and use it at the same time. That's just the way it is; You need to finish the declaration statement before you can use the new variable.

What you could have done though, and I am frankly *somewhat lost* as to why this has not been mentioned yet, is this:

```
if (my $attribute = $Data->{'is_new'} and $Data->{'is_new'} eq 'Y')
```

`$attribute` is not yet declared, but `$Data->{'is_new'}` *is*.

Just to be clear: The point of this if statement would then be three things:

- Initialize and assign a value to `$attribute`
- Check that this value is not undefined/empty string/zero
- Check if this value is `'Y'`

The lexical scope of `$attribute` is the inside of the if-statements subsequent block, no more, no less.